# MoveDataContext class was auto generated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

1st question:

[This link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/creating-model-classes-with-linq-to-sql-cs) says that `MoveDataContext` class was generated by the Visual Studio Object Relational Designer, but how would I know that that what name has been assigned to it by VS ?

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication1.Models;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
 [HandleError]
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
           var dataContext = new MovieDataContext();
           var movies = from m in dataContext.Movies
                select m;
           return View(movies);
      }
 }
}
```

2nd question:

what if i want to use external db e.g. from sql server 2008, so how it would be that case ? connection strings etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MovieDataContext` is a context class created on creation of entity framework. So you need to create the same.

For more `connectstring` [goto](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Basic

```
 Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
             User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: ok but how would i now that which class has been assigned which name ? i doesn't appear anywhere

Comment: Check link `The Index() action in Listing 1 uses a LINQ to SQL DataContext class (the MovieDataContext) to represent the MoviesDB database. The MoveDataContext class was generated by the Visual Studio Object Relational Designer.`

Comment: oh theek theek, Dhanivaad -Amit Agarwal

Comment: and answer to my 2nd question ?

Comment: sure it is but waiting for an answer to 2nd question actually

Comment: sir i tried but i know the syntax, worked a lot with web forms etc but want to know that what if i want to put connection string for db available in sql server etc

Comment: yes sir it's great but how to put it in model class and accessing it ?

Comment: You want total implementation. Here you can ask only your problem not the implementation